# Qt MySQL driver on windows (appveyor) doesn't support transactions feature

Tags: c++, mysql, windows, qt, appveyor

Qt MySQL driver on windows (appveyor) doesn't support transactions feature; i.e.:

```
QSqlDatabase::database().driver()->hasFeature(QSqlDriver::Transactions); //returns false
QSqlDatabase::database().transaction(); //raises exception
```

The question is: ***What's wrong? / how to make it work?***

The same code works perfectly on linux (ubuntu and arch), but fails on windows, appveyor CI in my case, for example: https://ci.appveyor.com/project/konserw/koferta/build/devel-ci-281

Environment:

- Visual Studio 2017
- MySQL 5.7
- Qt 5.11 (mysql plugin prebuilt on image, probably from qt binary distribution)
- Full list of sw: https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#pre-installed-software (VS 2017 column)

Link to sources: https://github.com/konserw/koferta/tree/devel

EDIT:

I've worked around this issue by checking if driver is supporting transactions and if not skipping transactions in my code. I'll live with that since it was appveyor/mysql only issue, so only my tests will run without transactions.

For production environment i've  copied over dll from mariadb c/c++ connector binaries for windows to my application binary dir and it worked fine with my (remote) linux/mariadb server.

Comment: Build it on your own system first before going to appveyor.

Comment: I've built it on my own Arch linux system without problems. Point of having automated CI with various platforms is not to have all those platforms home.

Comment: That’s the goal once the first build works. To debug the first build, you need your own system. CI systems aren’t designed to debug your builds that were never debugged before. It was never their purpose.